# Dependency injection in asp.net core

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have following code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
      ...
      services.AddScoped<IWsApiProvider, WsApiProvider>();
      services.AddScoped<IApplicationUserRepository, ApplicationUserRepository>();
      ...
    }
```

WsApiProvider has following:

```
public Guid SessionId { get; set; }
public IWSocketProvider WsApi { get; set; }
```

In Invoke method I'm updating these properties:

```
public Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
    {
      ...
      this._wsApiProvider.SessionId = sessionGuid;
      this._wsApiProvider.WsApi = connection;
      ...
    }
```

And then I'm going to Controller where I injected Repository:

```
public AccountController(IApplicationUserRepository applicationUserRepository)
    {
        this._applicationUserRepository = applicationUserRepository;
    }

    public ApplicationUserRepository(IWsApiProvider wsApi) : base(wsApi)
    { 
    }
```

And here I have wsApi object with empty properties. Two questions:

1. Why in repository constructor I have this object with empty properties?
2. Is there any way to create one instance of IWsApiProvider for all dependencies per request (non-singleton solution)?

Thank you in advance

UPDATED. The whole middleware class:

```
public class WsApiMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly IWsApiProvider _wsApiProvider;
    private const string QisSessionId = "QisSessionId";

    public WsApiMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IWsApiProvider wsApiProvider)
    {
        _next = next;
        this._wsApiProvider = wsApiProvider;
    }


    public Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
    {
        var sessionId = httpContext.Request.Cookies[QisSessionId];
        var sessionGuid = Guid.Empty;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sessionId))
        {
            Guid.TryParse(sessionId, out sessionGuid);
        }

        var connection = ConnectionsPool.GetSocket(sessionGuid);

        if (connection == null)
        {
            connection = new WSocketProvider(null);

            var connectTask = Task.Run(async () =>
            await connection.Connect(appSettings.Value.WsApiServerEndPointUri, CancellationToken.None)
            );

            Task.WaitAll(connectTask);

            var sessionService = new SessionService(connection);

            var sessionOpenTask = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                SessionDataState sessionData = null;

                //TODO [W-8/6/2017] - think about better solution for situation when sessionId doesn't exist on the server
                try
                {
                    sessionData = await sessionService.OpenSession(sessionGuid != Guid.Empty ? (Guid?)sessionGuid : null);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    sessionData = await sessionService.OpenSession();
                }

                sessionGuid = sessionData.SessionId;

                if (!sessionData.ClientType.HasValue)
                {
                    await sessionService.LoginClient();
                }

                ConnectionsPool.TryAddConnection(sessionGuid, connection);
                httpContext.Response.Cookies.Append(QisSessionId, sessionGuid.ToString());
            });

            Task.WaitAll(sessionOpenTask);
        }

        this._wsApiProvider.SessionId = sessionGuid;
        this._wsApiProvider.WsApi = connection;

        return this._next(httpContext);
    }
}

// Extension method used to add the middleware to the HTTP request pipeline.
public static class WsApiMiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseWsApiMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<WsApiMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does the Invoke method comes from? And what's _wsApiProvider?

Comment: Invoke method comes from MiddleWare.cs which has been registered in startup:app.UseWsApiMiddleware();

IWsApiProvider is a simple interface with two properties:
public Guid SessionId { get; set; }
public IWSocketProvider WsApi { get; set; }

Comment: Do you pass `IWSocketProvider` as an argument to `Middleware.cs`, or do you build it there?

Comment: Yes, I'm passing it as constructor parameter:

public WsApiMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IWsApiProvider wsApiProvider)

Comment: Post more code; particularly the middleware would be of interest.

Comment: Added the whole middleware class implementation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [ASP.Net core middleware doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware) :

> Middleware is constructed *once per application lifetime*. Because middleware is constructed at app startup, not per-request, scoped lifetime services used by middleware constructors are not shared with other dependency-injected types during each request.

And the most important part in you situation:

> If you must share a scoped service between your middleware and other types, add these services to the `Invoke` method's signature. The `Invoke` method can accept additional parameters that are populated by dependency injection.

Since `IWsApiProvider` is a scoped service(i.e. per request), it should be passed as an argument to the Invoke method, as follow:

```cs
public class WsApiMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    // no longer passed in the constructor
    public WsApiMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    // passed as an argument to Invoke, via dependency injection
    public Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, IWsApiProvider wsApiProvider, IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
    {
        wsApiProvider.SessionId = "SessionId";
        wsApiProvider.WsApi = "WsApi";

        return this._next(httpContext);
    }
}
```